# How to stop k8s deployment at specified time?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking for an alternative solution to k8s resources ttl. From the docs, this feature is not supproted.

more info:

- I need ttl for dployments & services,
- the deployment may be still running but I will still want to delete it.

---

possible solutions:

1. setup an additional monitoring-deployment in the cluster and truck down other resources and stop/delete them at specified time.

   - disadvantage: I would like to avoid starting additional resources.
2. k8s cronjobs - create cronjobs for a single use.

   - disadvantage: how will I stop the cronjobs after they are done?

Is there any other solution? I'm finding it hard to belive that I'm the first one who needs this feature.

Comment: Can you use the HorizontalPodAutoscaler to have the replica count track actual load?  If you have an external metric service, you could probably configure HPA to scale on a time-based metric too.  (HPA might not allow you to scale down to zero replicas, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would the use-case for this feature? Now there's no way you can stop a deployment. What you can do is stop the app serving the traffic which can be done in two ways:

1. You can *delete* the service.
2. You can either change the *selectors in the service* manifest or the *labels in deployment* manifest.

Another way to achieve the same is to scale down the deployment to **zero replicas**.

Now you can do the same via **crontab** file in Linux. You should be running it at specified time and because it's a one time job for you and you want to delete the crontab after deployment is scaled, you can put the same condition in crontab too.

So your crontab file would contain the following lines:

Your crontab itself will run a *shell script* where it will be checking for the **elapsed time** for the your deployment.
**crontab.txt** running every minute
Contents of *crontab.txt*, shouldn't be alike but something like this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash script.sh
```

The contents of **script.sh**, shouldn't be alike but something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ttl=kubectl get deployment deployment-name -n deployment-namespace | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v "AGE"

##It will give output in the format as xxxh or xxxdxxxh, where xxx can be
##any number. You will have to come up with converting them to hours, and
##then compare it with your value.

if [ "$ttl" gt your-value ] #checks for TTL condition
then
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment deployment-name -n deployment-namespace #scales deployment to zero
crontab -r username #deletes crontab job
```

The above scripts are just a logic implementation and not ready to use.

Similar logic can be implemented in **kubernetes cronjob**. Run a shell script there and delete the kubernetes cron after *deployment is scaled* and *ttl is met*.

Comment: thanks. just to clerify the usecase - in local tests, im exposing docker-images using k8s to be used in tests. so when tests are passed/failed/stoped, I need to delete all resoruces: https://github.com/stavalfi/k8test

Comment: so what you can run is just a ```kubectl delete --all -n your-test-namespace``` or delete the namespace altogether ```kubectl delete ns your-test-namespace``` instead of scaling deployment to zero.